# I have sandisk cruzer force 16Gb thumb drive for booting linux

Tags: linux, boot, usb-flash-drive

I have a sandisk cruzer force 16Gb thumb drive that i want to use as a 'usb boot device' for an old laptop with no hard drive or windows recovery disk (IF it is possible).

I have seen mention of 'fixed drives' and 'U3' in relation to sandisk thumb drives that could cause problems in this area but have no idea what that refers to.

The laptop used to have win vista home basic as an oem install, runs an Intel Celeron M processor (somewhere between 1.6ghz and 2.3Ghz) and already has the maximum 2Gb Ram. Since there is a large cost issue with replacing the hard drive AND windows, due to failure of hard drive and loss of recovery disk, I thought I would try to use it with 'some version of Linux'.

Problem is I don't have a clue where to start, what version of linux would be best, or even HOW to do what needs to be done to run linux on this old laptop assuming it would even be possible to run linux from a 'bootable' thumb drive when the laptop has no internal hard drive. As far as I know everything else on the laptop works including the dvd writer. If I would still need to have an internal hard drive in the old laptop in order to make the laptop work with Linux, then I will probably not bother since I can't waste money on buying storage I don't need (I have multiple sd cards and compact flash cards as well as multiple blank dvd's that can serve that purpose)

I do have access to another windows vista pc to download 'linux' on to the thumb drive, but what i would do next I have no idea.

Any constructive answers are or would be very greatly appreciated. Many thanks for your time :) :)

Bob

Comment: Which Linux distro is the "best" is entirely subjective and thus off-topic, so that part of your question is best edited out or ignored.

Comment: If you're new to Linux, start with a user-friendly distro from a major player (Mint is a good first distro, OpenSUSE is another; everyone will have an opinion).  2 GB is technically adequate for almost anything but it doesn't give you much space for RAM-hungry, or multiple concurrent, apps.  You will save a good chunk of that RAM if you avoid the heaviest desktops (like full-blown KDE).  Mate is a pretty full-featured desktop that is pretty Windows-like and uses reasonable RAM.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net) to automatically download and create a Ubuntu LiveUSB with persistence:

[image: 1]

This will quite likely kill your flash drive fairly quickly though depending on the amount of data written to it.

Comment: If you are familiar with powershell using winDD via powershell OR cp -r

Comment: @linuxdev2013: I don't quite understand your comment. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: powershell is command line FOR Windows   WinDD is a 3rd party program aimed at mimicking ` dd `  in linux/mac and cp -r  NON-Destructive recursively copies the data to some destination drive/folder

Comment: @linuxdev2013: Great! So what does any of that have to do with my answer?

Comment: those are 3 separate ways to create an installer

Comment: @linuxdev2013: Oh ok, so you're talking about how to transfer the contents of a Linux distro ISO to a USB stick. Yes, there are lots of ways but given his apparent skill level I suggested UNetbootin, which will do everything for him including downloading the ISO, transferring its contents onto the USB stick and making it bootable (which BTW I don't think cp -r will do).

Comment: Unetbootin is known to be buggy on non Ubuntu (or ubuntu based distros) for ex  my fedora isos NEVER come out right or bootable with unetbootin

Comment: @linuxdev2013: Perhaps. Can't say for sure since I've never used it for Fedora, only Ubuntu, Debian, Mint and DSL. Fedora is on the supported list though so if it really is a bug you should report it to the developers.

Comment: Has been reported the developers seem to not care...  As such IT IS NOT on the list of supported / official recommended options on the Fedora side of things.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all modern (post 2000) Linux distribution(s) (aka distro(s)) can / do run on older hardware to include the one you mentioned having FROM a USB stick AND with under 2Gb RAM with or without swap (aka page file in windows -- drive space used as additional ram)  which can be used FROM a USB with noticeable degrading of life cycle of the USB and its r/w I/O speeds.    As a reference I run a copy of  Fedora 22 and Linux Mint 17.1 (both released within last 8 months on a Dell D820 with 3Gb of DDR2 ram)

Almost any particular distros' wiki page (notably the Arch and Red Hat ones  links below) that thoroughly explain the processes and best practices.

[Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/)

[REd Hat Enterprise Linux Documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/)

Comment: Running without a swap file is fine and all, but since he has no hard drive at all he'll have to use persistence and that will degrade the USB stick depending on the amount of data written, just like I mentioned.